# Application on IIS does not able to launch Adobe Illustrator

Tags: c#, iis, com, adobe-illustrator

My application makes use of Adobe Illustrator on the server side to complete some routine tasks. It is working fine on IIS Express for development, however when it runs on IIS for production it throws the following error:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80080005): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {F66C7D88-4EEB-4A9B-BBF2-D229C9C46870} failed due to the following error: 80080005 Server execution failed (Exception from HRESULT:0x80080005 (CO_E_SERVER_EXEC_FAILURE)).
```

The code to launch Adobe Illustrator is straightforward:

```
var app = new Application();
```

I have tried to elevate the privilege of the app pool to administrator, and add permission in COM settings in computer management too. But none of them help to resolve the issue. I wonder if there is any difference for the permission model between IIS Express and IIS, which makes IIS Express work but not IIS. Could anyone help please?

Thank you!

Comment: Does IIS Express run as an application and not a service? Yes, a service is an application, but it is launched from the service manager. If IIS Express is launched from a command line or from a shortcut, then it is running as a desktop application. Desktop applications have more resources, specifically more desktop heap. You might be running out of desktop heap. Here is one article, by reading it you might find similar articles describing  problems/solutions: https://support.tibco.com/s/article/How-to-increase-non-interactive-desktop-heap-size-for-better-performance-with-MAS-and-WebStatistica

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 You won't be able to get the same when running on IIS.

Comment: I guess this issue may be related with permission settings. I suggest you could try below solutions: 

1.IIS manager->application pool ->set application pool identity
2.Configure the account with administrator account
3.Computer management->services-> IIS admin service ->properties->login -> enable “allow service interact with desktop” configuration
4.IIS manager-> .NET trust level->full->apply

Comment: were you able to find the solution for this problem?